# Rspec and spawn gem: How to test "should_receive" in spawned_out process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spawn

I have a controller action which calls a spawn block

```
class MyController <  ApplicationController
  ....
  def send_product_mails
    if @user.has_rights?
        spawn_block(:nice => 19 ) do 
          @current_product.send_mail
        end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

and I want to spec thet send_mail is called on @current_product, but it tells me it didn't receive it.. How should one do it?

My Spec looks like so:

```
it "works with spawn" do
  # Setup: create Product, Usersession (via UserSession.create(user))
  get :send_product_mails, :id => product.id
  MyController.any_instance.should_receive(:spawn_block).and_yield("sd")
end
```

I want to spec that something is passed to the `spawn_block` if the user has the rights, and nothing otherwise. Right now with different trys (calling `.should_receive` in the test on MyController, MyController.any_instance, @controller, with or without and_yield this always gives errors that the message `spawn_block` wasn't received. (Yes, I checked that the rights are acutally okay by adding a puts-debug-output within the if-statement.)

EDIT: Gave more context and code to the question, and what I've tried

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to do this without stubbing spawn_block - your should_receive isn't going to work cross-process

Comment: okay so I do something like `MyController.should_receive(:spawn_block)`.. but this doesn't work, how should I do it?

Comment: You'd to use and_yield so that your block is executed

Comment: @FrederickCheung The problem lies deeper I suppose, the error messages are `Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: spawn_block` or    `(<MyController (class)>).spawn_block(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times`

So it doesn't see it's received in the first place

Comment: well you need to be calling should _receive on the instance of the controller, not on the class (unless there is some class method involved)

Comment: @FrederickCheung I've tried it via `MyController.any_instance.should_receieve(:spawn_block)` - this is what gives the first error I showed, the second one is when I do it via class itself.. Is it possible that it doesn't work with "any_instance", but I can get it to work with the specific one (I am not sure how I an obtain it)

Comment: @controller is the controller instance used in a controller spec. You need the and_yield or else the block will not run

Comment: It is okay for me that the block doesn't run.. I just want to spec that "something" happens, so I want to assert that `spawn_block` is called.. However with (I used `@controller.should_receive(:spawn_block).and_yield("sd")`) or without `.and_yield` it tells me that it didn't receive `spawn_block`

Comment: Are you sure that spawn_block is being called?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I updated the question to give more details. In the console output when I run the test with rspec it tells me "spawn> parent PID = 5060
spawn> child PID = 5064
spawn> child[5064] took 0.001086 sec".. so yes, it is called and the spec results in ` @controller.should_receive(:spawn_block).and_yield("sd")
       (#<MyController:0x7f29dea299f0>).spawn_block(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the expectation (the call to should_receive) *before* the code under test runs.

Comment: Thank you :) In this example I didn't see that this was the problem.. Now it works :)